# Is it an issue if there's a large skip in primary keys?

Tags: sql, database, django

I'm using Django and loading in a bulk amount of data with manual commits and transactions. However, my laptop froze in the middle so I had to restart, and I resumed where I left off. I was letting Django automatically create my primary keys for me, but I guess due to the restart, the rows in my field uses primary keys 1 to 80,0000, and then skips to about 150,000. So no primary key exists roughly between 80k and 150k, but everything else is fine. I'm wondering if there's an issue with this gap? I'm never going to be doing primary key lookups, since they're just arbitrary numbers.

Answer (score 1):

No, I can't think of any reason why this would be a problem. As you say, the keys are arbitrary.